# React: Change component's children from the outside

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React project, I have a component `Header.js`, which is part of the global layout and is used on every page. Routing is done with **React Router v4**.

The `Header.js` component should have different children (like breadcrumbs or titles), depending on the page I'm currently on.

*Example: on the `HomePage.js`, I want to display breadcrumbs. But on the `AboutPage.js`, I want to have just a title.*

```
<App>
  <Header />

  <AnotherComponent />
  <MoreComponents />
  <BrowserRouter>
  ...
  </BrowserRouter>
</App>
```

I thought about making `Header.js` a HOC, but I can't embed it onto every page because of layout and styling reasons. It needs to be in `App.js` in the exact same position.

Any ideas / techniques?

**EDIT:** Ideally, I want to have the content of `Header.js` in every page, like the Helmet package does it:

```
<>
  {/* HomePage.js */}
  <HeaderPortal>
    <p>Content for the header</p>
  </HeaderPortal>

  <PageContent />
</>
```

Comment: You can nest routes that renders the component you want inside the `<Header />`, if some of them needs to address multiple routes you can match it against a regex

Comment: Yeah, I thought about the same, but I would like to keep the `<Header />` clean and not put all the content inside it. The content that is going to be displayed in `<Header />` should come from the page components.

Comment: If you render `children` then the `App` can nest those routes. Or maybe use react portals (which i think is less preferred for this use case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is by using React's context API, but you'll have to wrap pretty high in the DOM to be able to provide the setters and getters of the header content from wherever.

The Header components would look like this:

```
const HeaderContext = React.createContext();

// Provides the context and state - wrap app
export class HeaderProvider extends React.Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    return (
      <HeaderContext.Provider
        value={{
          header: this.state.header,
          setHeader: ({ header }) => this.setState({ header })
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </HeaderContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
// Wrapper around WHERE the header will be rendered
export function HeaderPlacement() {
  return (
    <HeaderContext.Consumer>{({ header }) => header}</HeaderContext.Consumer>
  );
}
// Wrapper for setting the header CONTENT
export function HeaderPortal({ children }) {
  return (
    <HeaderContext.Consumer>
      {({ header, setHeader }) => 
        !header // Guard against setting the header in an endless loop
        && setHeader({ header: children })}
    </HeaderContext.Consumer>
  );
}
```

And then the usage would look like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <HeaderProvider>
      <div className="App">
        <HeaderPlacement />
        <Page />
      </div>
    </HeaderProvider>
  );
}

function Page() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <HeaderPortal><h1>Page A Test</h1></HeaderPortal>
      <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In ex odio,
        eleifend in consequat nec, maximus lobortis ligula. Duis elementum, diam
        et imperdiet pulvinar, nulla ligula commodo elit, ac ullamcorper justo
        mauris quis velit. 
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

You'll have to be careful if multiple descendants try setting the header content, because you will either end up with a looping `setState` issue, or one will overwrite the other.

This is definitely not the only way, and I avoided using hooks, but this is certainly *a* React-y way.

Checkout the codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/pj2q10700j

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort. I'm still trying to wrap my mind around this, but it seems like a great solution. In the meantime, I figured something out using React Router, which is quite different to your solution but achieves the same (more or less). Thanks anyway for your suggestion, I'll accept it as the best answer.